# Skip PAM authentication module for specific SSH certificates

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

I use Yubikey's PAM module as an extra layer of authentication on my server.

I want to skip this authentication module when a device tries to authenticate using a specific SSH certificate.

I know it's possible to do this for certain IPs/subnets using `access.conf` - is there a possibility to filter access by SSH certificate?

Ideally one certificate would skip the extra authentication module, while all others would do the full authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the sshd_config directive [Match](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match).

You could try to write something like this (not tested):

```
Match User certsysuser1
    AuthenticationMethods publickey
    UsePAM no
```

In this example `certsysuser1` is the principal name (vulgo user name) in the OpenSSH certs.